# Java Stanford NLP: Find word frequency?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using the Stanford NLP Parsing toolkit. Given a word in the lexicon, how can I find its frequency*? Or, given a frequency rank, how can I determine the corresponding word?

*in the entire language, not just the text sample.

This is a demo of the toolkit I'm using:

```
class ParserDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LexicalizedParser lp = new LexicalizedParser("englishPCFG.ser.gz");
    lp.setOptionFlags(new String[]{"-maxLength", "80", "-retainTmpSubcategories"});

    String[] sent = { "Sincerity", "may", "frighten", "the", "boy", "." };
    Tree parse = (Tree) lp.apply(Arrays.asList(sent));
    parse.pennPrint();
    System.out.println();

    TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
    GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
    GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
    Collection tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCollapsed();
    System.out.println(tdl);
    System.out.println();

    TreePrint tp = new TreePrint("penn,typedDependenciesCollapsed");
    tp.printTree(parse);
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. What does finding word frequencies have to do with parsing?

Comment: I want to get a measure of someone's vocabulary by looking at the lexical frequency of the words the use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only counting word frequencies, sentence parsing is unnecessary. All you need to do is *tokenise* the input and then count word frequencies using a java `HashMap`. If you want to use the Stanford tools, then use any of the tokenisers in `edu.stanford.nlp.process`.

This gives you the frequency of any given word, but in general it may not be possible to find the word corresponding to a given frequency rank, since some words may be equally frequent in the document.

Comment: the Lexicon interface seems like it could be useful, but how do I fill it with data?

Comment: It's probably not useful for your needs, you may be getting misled by the name. Lexicon is a subcomponent of the parser which "provide(s) a conditional probability P(word|tag)". Lexicon is not designed to count word frequencies.

Comment: I'm not concerned with counting word frequencies in the text sample, but in the entire corpus. (so "the" would be a more frequent word than "pumpernickel")

Answer (score 0):

This is an IR (information retrieval) problem more than NLP. One should look at libraries like [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) for this task.